# My first linear algebra proof - is it accurate and written correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, systems-of-equations, solution-verification

This is the first proof exercise from "Linear Algebra as an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics." It also happens to be my first proof (outside of proving things like properties of integers and trigonometric identities). I'm hoping someone can critique it and let me know what I did right or what I did wrong.

**Problem**: Let a, b, c, and d be real numbers. Consider the system of equations (1):
$$ax_1 + bx_2 = 0$$
$$cx_1 + dx_2 = 0$$

Note that $x_1=x_2=0$ is a solution for any choice of a, b, c, and d. 
Prove that, if $ad-bc\neq0$, then $x_1=x_2=0$ is the only solution.

**Proof**: We will prove by contrapositive. Assume $x_1=x_2=0$ is not the only solution. Assume
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}, X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}, 0 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Then the system of equations (1) is equivalent to the expression $AX=0$ (2). For (2) to be true, we must have either $A=0$ or $X=0$. Since we are assuming $x_1=x_2=0$ is not the only solution, we assume $X\neq0$. Then, for (2) to be true, we must have $A=0$, and therefore, $a=b=c=d=0$. If $a=b=c=d=0$, then $ab-cd=0$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is not correct. Matrices don't behave like real numbers. If $Ax=0$, it's definitely possible that $A\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$. In fact, this is called the null space of the matrix $A$. Have you learned about determinants and inverses? In my opinion, the best way to go is to use the formula for $A$ inverse (if you must, you can prove this formula holds). Then multiply both sides of $Ax=0$ by $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following row operations in order to get that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
ax_{1} + bx_{2} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases} & \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
acx_{1} + bcx_{2} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0 
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(acx_{1} + bcx_{2}) - (acx_{1} + adx_{2}) = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(bc - ad)x_{2} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Similarly, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
ax_{1} + bx_{2} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases} & \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
adx_{1} + bdx_{2} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases}\\\\ & \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(adx_{1} + bx_{2}) - (bcx_{1} + bdx_{2}) = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases}\\\\ & \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(ad-bc)x_{1} = 0\\\\
cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since $ad - bc \neq 0$, we get that the solution set $S\subseteq\{(0,0)\}$.

Once $x_{1} = x_{2} = 0$ is a solution, it is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Claiming that $AX =0$ implies either $A =0$ or $X= 0$ does not always hold true. Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

$X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $

Then $AX = 0$ while neither $A$ nor $B$ is actually zero.

The condition $ad-bc \neq 0$ means that the determinant of $A$ is not zero, which means that $A$ is invertible. This means that $AX = 0 \implies X = IX = A^{-1}AX = A^{-1}O = 0$. It follows that $X = 0$ is the only solution.

Comment: This makes sense. I felt like I might be making some false assumptions there, that's the main reason I posted. I have just a very computational and basic understanding of matrices, and this proof is actually before matrices are even introduced in this particular text. I think I follow your explanation for why X=0 would be the only solution, but if you're willing, do you have any thoughts on how I might go about proving this without matrices at all?

Comment: Alternatively, write: 
$ax_{1} + bx_{2} = 0$ (1)
$cx_{1} + dx_{2} = 0$ (2)

Multiply (1) by d and subtract b times (2) from it to get $(ad-bc)x_{1} =0$. Then $x_{1} =0$ since $ad-bc \neq 0$. 

Now we have $bx_{2} = 0$ and $dx_{2} =0$. Both $b$ and $d$ cannot be zero and so $x_{2} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $ad-bc\ne 0$ and that $(x_1,x_2)$ is a solution.
Then in particular
$$0 = d\cdot 0 - b \cdot 0 = d(ax_1+bx_2) - b(cx_1+dx_2) = (ad-bc)x_1 \implies x_1 = 0$$
$$0 = -c \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 = -c(ax_1+bx_2) +a(cx_1+dx_2) = (ad-bc)x_2 \implies x_2 = 0$$
so $(x_1,x_2) = (0,0)$. Hence $(0,0)$ is the only solution.